# SET NO Count ON in SQl Server Causes an issue with ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

According to the most of the SQL texts that I have seen

```
SET NoCount ON
```

Add's to the DB performance and DBA's don't like to see it OFF.

However in the ASP.NET that i'm dealing with , this causes

Calling  to the stored procedures using `ExecuteNonQuery` always result in -1.

Is this a known issue and if so what is the workaround?

So the question is how have  `SET NoCount ON` and then `ExecuteNonQuery` return number of rows affected.

This question is for '`ExecuteNonQuery`' only. I know I can use `ExecuteScalar` and get the `@@RowCount`

Comment: What's the query? How are you calling it?

Comment: You mean `ExecuteNonQuery` right?

Comment: Yes, Edited my question. tnx.

Comment: @artm Any simple stored procedure which does insert of delete.

Comment: Based on the documentation of [`NoCount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx) your only option is to use `@@RowCount` if you have to turn it on.

Comment: And using  @@RowCount mean I cannot use ExecutenonQuery

Comment: @SNash correct, but whether you turn `NoCount` off or use `@@RowCount` should probably be based on the procedure.  If it's just one statement then there isn't much point in turning `NoCount` on.  If there are multiple statements then maybe `@@RowCount` would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What else did you expect? You explicitely tell the database to **not** count the rows and then you are asking why the counted rows are not returned?

The database does not deliver the number of rows affected, *because you turned it off*. That's neither an issue nor a bug, that's the whole point of what you did.

Comment: Yes I wished I could just delete the line. However is this going to be big deal for my DB performance in the future?

Comment: It won't be a performance issue for the DB since it isn't global. This is the one case where you really do want it on and not off.

Comment: Well I guess this is what it is . I have to stop using ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: @SNash Usually the point of `NoCount` is for procedures that have multiple statements or especially statements in a loop.  If you're just doing one statement I doubt there would be much of a performance difference.  Especially since you want that information sent to you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked the db not to return that information, it does exactly what you said.

You could try to prefix your queries with `SET NOCOUNT OFF` and postfix with `SET NOCOUNT ON` to get the number of rows for specific cases

Comment: `Set NoCount` does not change the global default.  It only effects the current procedure, so you don't have to restore the setting at the end of a procedure.